# "Cannot reference a field before it is defined" in Forge Modding

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

**Short Question:** How do I resolve two errors in my Forge Mod code?

**Long Question/Information Required:**

I am creating a Forge Mod that expands upon what Diamonds can do but I have run into an issue when making a "Block Item," which is the representation of a block in an inventory. The Forge MDK I am using is the `forge-1.15.2-31.2.0-mdk`.

On line 32 of the code below, I am getting two errors.

The first one is for `new BlockItemBase()`, and the error is `The constructor BlockItemBase(Item) is undefined.` There are two "Quick Fixes" but when I try them it results in another error in another Class.

The second one is for the `CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM`. The error is `Cannot reference a field before it is defined.` There aren't any quick fixes here.

If it helps, I am using Eclipse IDE and both errors are classified as "Java Errors." I'm not sure if other new Forge Developers run into this problem but I couldn't find any solution to this issue. Finally, please let me know if you need any more information.

**The Code:**

```
package pw.AbyssStudios.ExtenDiamonds.util;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.RegistryObject;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
import pw.AbyssStudios.ExtenDiamonds.ExtenDiamonds;
import pw.AbyssStudios.ExtenDiamonds.blocks.BlockItemBase;
import pw.AbyssStudios.ExtenDiamonds.blocks.ConcentratedDiamondBlock;
import pw.AbyssStudios.ExtenDiamonds.items.ItemBase;

public class RegistryHandler {
    
    public static final DeferredRegister<Item> ITEMS = new DeferredRegister<>(ForgeRegistries.ITEMS, ExtenDiamonds.MOD_ID);
    public static final DeferredRegister<Block> BLOCKS = new DeferredRegister<>(ForgeRegistries.BLOCKS, ExtenDiamonds.MOD_ID);
    
    public static void init() {

        ITEMS.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());
        BLOCKS.register(FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus());
    }
    
    //ITEMS
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> DIAMOND_APPLE = ITEMS.register("diamond_apple", ItemBase::new);
    
    //BLOCKS
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK = BLOCKS.register("concentrated_diamond_block", ConcentratedDiamondBlock::new);
    
    //BLOCKITEMS
    public static final RegistryObject<Item> CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM = ITEMS.register("concentrated_diamond_block", () -> new BlockItemBase(CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM.get())); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create `CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM`, you require an instance of `BlockItemBase`, which requires `CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM`.
This is a circular reference. The supplier is pointing to a **not existing reference **.

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM = 
     ITEMS.register("concentrated_diamond_block",
     () -> new BlockItemBase(/*here you cannot use reference to CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM */));
```

Because you are using a reference inside of a lambda expression, this reference has to be final, so here you need to find another way to create `BlockItemBase` supplier.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Beri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086177/beri) said, you are referencing the object itself (CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM is referencing CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM). I am pretty sure what you want to do is:

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK_ITEM = ITEMS.register("concentrated_diamond_block", () -> new BlockItemBase(CONCENTRATED_DIAMOND_BLOCK.get()));
```

because `BlockItemBase` takes a Block as input (not an item).